# Using hpple in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, hpple

I am using hpple in Swift and would like to use the same syntax.

Objective-C works perfectly:

```
myElement.title = [[element firstChild] content];
```

Swift does not compile:

```
myelement.title = element.firstchild.content
```

I receive the error TFHppleElement! does not have a member named 'content'

On the other hand, the following works fine which shows that specifcally *myElement* and hpple seem to be set up correctly:

```
myElement.url = element.objectForKey("href")  // Works fine
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstchild` is likely returning an optional since there may be no first child.  You'll need to unwrap that optional to use it.  I suggest:

```
if let content = element.firstchild?.content {
    myelement.title = content
}
```

If `myelement.title` is also an optional, you could do:

```
myelement.title = element.firstchild?.content
```

Comment: Thanks, works now. I didn't add the optional but that did the trick!